# What is the probability that a randomly chosen point of a square of side length $a$ is more than a distance $r$ away from every corner?

Tags: probability

What is the probability that a randomly chosen point of a square of side length $a$ is more than a distance $r$ away from every corner? Suppose $r<\frac a2$.

Comment: What have you tried? What is the context? Please show your efforts so that others avoid repeating the same work and can also see that you care enough to actually try solving the problem. See [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/595055).

Comment: Is the point randomly chosen from inside the square or chosen from the boundary of the square?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The probability that your randomly chosen point does not lay on that region is obviously the area of circle with radius $r$ divided by $a^2$ (the area of the square), which would be equal to $ \pi r^2/a^2$. Hence your answer would be $1-\pi r^2/a^2$